# Use .htaccess rewrite rules on Microsoft IIS

Tags: iis, .htaccess

In the last few days there's been reports [[1](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/04/huge-attack-on-wordpress-sites-could-spawn-never-before-seen-super-botnet/)][[2](http://calladeveloper.blogspot.se/2013/04/global-wordpress-brute-force-attacks.html)] of an attack targeting WordPress sites. In [this blog post](http://calladeveloper.blogspot.se/2013/04/global-wordpress-brute-force-attacks.html) it is described how to mitigate automatic login attempts using `.htaccess` with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)?.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

How could this be made to work with Microsoft IIS? Can `.htaccess` be used with IIS as is, or does it have to be converted? If so, what would be the quickest way to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.htaccess` rewrite rules so I'm not sure what they do. Those rules were the ones recommended in the blog post I referred to. I have however pasted them into the root `.htaccess` of a site running Apache (and changed the domain name) and had no problems logging in.

Answer (score 0):

> Can .htaccess be used with IIS as is, or does it have to be converted?

Yes, the corresponding part for .htaccess for IIS is web.config file, you should be able to find it under your wordpress root folder.

> How could this be made to work with Microsoft IIS?

It seems to me that the .htaccess piece you provided was trying to block access to wp-admin and wp-login.php and give out and 403 (Access Denied) to the requester. You can follow the following steps to achieve this:

1, Open the web.config file in your wordpress root folder, if you don't find it there, create one

2, Enable "IP and Domain Restrictions" role by following [this article](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity)

3, Open IIS Manager, click on root node, in the right panel, select "Feature Delegation", find "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" item, grant "Read/Write" delegation to it

4, Open the web.config file, if you created the file yourself and it's empty, then add the following code(see notes at the bottom for explanation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <location path="wp-login.php">
        <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">    
                <clear/>
                <add ipAddress="100.100.100.29" allowed="true"/>
                <add ipAddress="111.111.111.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
  </location>

  <location path="wp-admin">
        <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">    
                <clear/>
                <add ipAddress="100.100.100.29" allowed="true"/>
                <add ipAddress="111.111.111.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

If you are working on an existing web.config file, then you only need to add code between  tags into the existing  tags in your web.config.

Explanation: This code blocks all IPs from visiting wp-login.php or wp-admin, exceptions are IPs 100.100.100.29 and 111.111.111.1-255. Please replace these IPs with your own list.

5, Now try visit wp-login.php or wp-admin from IPs that are not in the list, you should be given a 403 - Access Denied error.